# Python SAX - extract xml code

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, sax

I am using Python SAX to parse large xml files (2+ GB), compare them, and then create a new xml file. For the creating I would like to take part of the code starting at a tag and ending at the tag's end and pass it into a new xml file. In other words, from this xml file:

```
<collection>
<record>
  <leader> lorem ipsum </leader>
  <controlfield tag="1">aa</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="2">bb</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="3">cc</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="4">dd</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="a">
    <subfield code="1">ee</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="b">
    <subfield code="1">ff</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="c">
    <subfield code="1">gg</subfield>
    <subfield code="2">hh</subfield>
    <subfield code="3">ii</subfield>
    <subfield code="4">jj</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
</collection>
```

I would like to get everything between record and /record tag in the xml markup as a string. Can this be done with SAX or are there any other libraries that can do this?

Comment: a) Could you provide more details on what you're trying to achieve? Are you comparing files between each other or check a condition on every record?
b) How would you compare 2 files in case there's a record in the beginning of the first file and the same record in the end of the second file - what should be in the resulting file?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because it is not asking for a way to capture text *between* tags. It is asking about how to grab a sequence of elements (everything between the `<record>` tags).

Comment: Exactly, my problem was getting all of the elements in between plus the text between tags. In the end I've made an empty string everytime a record element was found and appended to it any element met after it as a string. This however feels brutish and has led to non pretty code when elements with multiple tags were introduced.

Comment: @martijn-pieters this is wrong. This is not a duplicate. Question is not about collecting just text between two tags, but rather all tags AND texts between them. The reply is that author has to collect all events into some kind of list or something like it, and then send it somewhere else.